# add trailing slash and remove .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

How can I do something like this that:
website.com/store/ redirect to website.com/store
website.com/outbound/store/5 redirect to website.com/outbound/store/5/

what I want is to have for urls without prefix to remove trailing slash and for those with prefix to add trailing slash

my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^pa/?$ /admin/index.php [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ stores.php?store=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^outbound/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /outbound.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: What do you mean with prefix?

Comment: By prefix I mean some constant like in last line 'outbound'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# force tailing slash for all urls starting with /outbound/
RewriteRule ^outbound/.*[^/]$ /$0/ [R=301,L]

#remove tailing slash for all except urls starting with /outbound/
RewriteCond $1 !^outbound/
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^pa/?$ /admin/index.php [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^outbound/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /outbound.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ stores.php?store=$1 [L]
```

I also cleaned it up a bit.